# How do I create a Database Icon in Canvas using Easel.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, easeljs

I am trying to create a re-sizable database icon in canvas using Easel.js. I figured out how to create the base cylinder but cannot figure out the curves for the stacks. The database icon should look like this link below:

http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/256/Data-Database-icon.png

I have started the creation of of the icon on JSFiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/rsperlazza/u6Uaq/

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage($("#test")[0]);
stage.enableMouseOver(50);
stage.canvas.width = 500;
stage.canvas.height = 500;

var shape = new createjs.Shape();  

var g = shape.graphics;
var x = 50;
var y = 100;
var width = 100;
var height = 120;

g.beginStroke("red");     
g.beginFill("black");

g.drawEllipse(x, y, width, height / 4);     
g.moveTo(x, y + height / 8);
g.lineTo(x, y + 7 * height / 8);
g.moveTo(x, y + height / 8);
g.lineTo(x, y + 7 * height / 8);
g.drawEllipse(x, y + 3 * height / 4, width, height / 4);
g.endStroke();

g.drawRect(x, y + height / 8, width, 3 * height / 4);
stage.addChild(shape);    
stage.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at either Flash CS6 or Flash CC's Toolkit for CreateJS panel. You can create as complex a shape as you want, and it will export it. You have to download it for Flash CS6 (http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/flash/flash-to-html5.html), but it comes with newer versions.

The other easy approach is drawscri.pt, and Illustrator panel that exports vectors to various formats, including EaselJS Graphics. Note that it won't have full Illustrator vector support, but it does a pretty good job. http://drawscri.pt/